# Create array from several objects with merging keys by object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've stucked in one thing. I've checked existing questions but didn't find good solution. I need to create array like this from 3 objects.

```
    var object1 = {
    1: { name: 'name1' },
    2: { name: 'name2' },
    3: { name: 'name3' },
    };

    var object2 = {
    1: [1,2,3],
    2: [4,5,6],
    3: [7,8,9],
    };

    var object3 = {
    1: { sport: 'football' },
    2: { sport: 'hockey' },
    3: { sport: 'snooker' },
    4: { sport: 'walleyball' },
    5: { sport: 'moto' },
    6: { sport: 'f1' },
    7: { sport: 'boxing' },
    8: { sport: 'karate' },
    9: { sport: 'ufc' },
    };
```

In final I need to get array with object that will have this view.

```
    var array = [
    { 
      name: 'name1',
      sports: [ 
       { sport: 'football' },
       { sport: 'hockey'},
       { sport: 'snooker' }
     ] 
    },
    { 
      name: 'name2',
      sports: [ 
       { sport: 'walleyball' },
       { sport: 'moto'},
       { sport: 'f1' }
     ] 
    },
      { 
        name: 'name3',
        sports: [ 
        { sport: 'boxing' },
        { sport: 'karate'},
        { sport: 'ufc' }
     ] 
    },
    ];
```

`Object1` main category, `Object2` sport options, `Object3` all existing sports

My attempt :

```
const categoriesWithSports = {};
const categorySportsNew = { ...object2 };

Object.keys(categorySportsNew).forEach(sportsId => {

    const currentCategoryArray = object2[sportsId];

    const sportsWithCategoriesArray = currentCategoryArray.map(sportNewId => 
    {
        Object.keys(object3).forEach(sportsKey => {

            const currentSport = sportsId[sportsKey];
            return currentSport;
        });

        categorySportsNew[sportsId] = sportsWithCategoriesArray;
    });
});
```

After that I am getting infinity loop.

Comment: Can you please share your attempt as well?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: @Cerbrus I agree and posting here questions really rarely. Code added.

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, why haven't you picked an answer yet? If not, why haven't you commented accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate over the objects and make the right connections. I've renamed the objects for better code readability.

```js
const people = {
  1: { name: 'name1' },
  2: { name: 'name2' },
  3: { name: 'name3' },
};

const sportsoptions = {
  1: [1,2,3],
  2: [4,5,6],
  3: [7,8,9],
};

const sportsmap = {
  1: { sport: 'football' },
  2: { sport: 'hockey' },
  3: { sport: 'snooker' },
  4: { sport: 'walleyball' },
  5: { sport: 'moto' },
  6: { sport: 'f1' },
  7: { sport: 'boxing' },
  8: { sport: 'karate' },
  9: { sport: 'ufc' },
};

const result = [];

for (const prop in people) {
  let person = { name: people[prop].name, sport: []};
  for (let sportsoption of sportsoptions[prop]) {
    person.sport.push({sport: sportsmap[sportsoption].sport})
  }
  result.push(person);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: 1: Your snippet is broken, somehow. There's no "run" button. 2: please don't use a `pre` to output results from a snippet. Just `console.log` it.

Comment: The missing run button I assume is due to the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal for loops to do this

```js
 var object1 = {
    1: { name: 'name1' },
    2: { name: 'name2' },
    3: { name: 'name3' },
    };

    var object2 = {
    1: [1,2,3],
    2: [4,5,6],
    3: [7,8,9],
    };

    var object3 = {
    1: { sport: 'football' },
    2: { sport: 'hockey' },
    3: { sport: 'snooker' },
    4: { sport: 'walleyball' },
    5: { sport: 'moto' },
    6: { sport: 'f1' },
    7: { sport: 'boxing' },
    8: { sport: 'karate' },
    9: { sport: 'ufc' },
    };
    
    var res = [];
    
    for(var key in object1) {
        let val = object1[key];
        let obj = {};
        obj['name'] = val.name;
        obj.sports = [];
        let secondVal = object2[key];
        secondVal.forEach(val => {
          let newObj = {};
          newObj['sport '] = object3[val]['sport'];
          obj.sports.push(newObj);
        })
       res.push(obj)
    }
    
    console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty clean with a `map()` inside a `map()`. It's only confusing because the original data is awkward and should probably be arrays instead of objects.

```js
var object1 = {1: { name: 'name1' },2: { name: 'name2' },3: { name: 'name3' },};
var object2 = {1: [1,2,3],2: [4,5,6],3: [7,8,9],};
var object3 = {1: { sport: 'football' },2: { sport: 'hockey' },3: { sport: 'snooker' },4: { sport: 'walleyball' },5: { sport: 'moto' },6: { sport: 'f1' },7: { sport: 'boxing' },8: { sport: 'karate' },9: { sport: 'ufc' },};

let res = Object.entries(object1).map(([k, v]) => {
    v.sports = object2[k].map(i => ({sport: object3[i].sport}))
    return v
})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: *It's a pretty simple map() inside a map()* you notice something?

Comment: Thanks @connexo fixed.

Comment: I honestly don't see why I'm getting more hate here.